# UISearchController not shown if not set in viewDidLoad method

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have a view controller that presents different child views. Each child view is created by view controller calling `UINib()` method and the view controller passes itself as a parameter to that view.

```
class func instanceFromNib(parentViewController: UIViewController) -> UIView {
    let view = UINib(nibName: "PodcastsPage", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! PodcastsPage
    view.viewController = parentViewController
    return view as UIView
}
```

As soon as the view receives a reference to its parent view controller it setups appropriate navigation bar

```
private var viewController: UIViewController! {
    didSet {
        setupNavigationBar()
    }
}
```

Inside the `setupNavigationBar()` I have code that should add `UISearchController` into the view controller's navigation bar

```
func setupNavigationBar() {
    guard let navigationBar = viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar else {
        return
    }

    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.barTintColor = .navigationBar
    navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        .font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 18.0)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.textPrimary
    ]

    viewController.navigationItem.title = "Follow Podcasts"

    let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Finish", style: .done, target: nil, action: nil)
    nextButton.tintColor = .orangePrimary
    viewController.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(nextButton, animated: false)

    // Set UISearchController here //
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    viewController.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    viewController.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

The `UISearchController` isn't visible when I run the app though
[image: not visible UISearchController]

However, if I set the `UISearchController` inside the view controller's `viewDidLoad` like so, the search bar is actually present.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```

What do I have to do to set up `UISearchController` from the child view?

Comment: have you tried setting it in the viewWillAppear() or viewDidAppear() methods??

Comment: @SamuelChavez I want to set the search bar in a child view - I cannot use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`